# Prepare String for URL cast in Swift

Tags: swift, url

I have a text Area, the content of which will later be used to create a URL. How can I validate that the url - cast doesn't throw an error? Is there a function that can do that? For example remove all invalid Characters. 
I cast the String in the following way, but if the user inputs a newline the cast doesn't work:
`let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!`

Comment: I would suggest to read the chapter about optionals again. `!` is a *forced unwrap* and can indeed crash your program. Look up “optional binding”!

Comment: Removing invalid characters is not going to give what the user asked for. `http://example.com/url with spaces` is invalid, but converting it to `http://example.com/urlwithspaces` isn't the answer. The system can tell you whether a string is a valid URL, but it can't tell you what the user experience should be. Do you want to restrict input (remembering that users can paste)? Do you want to display an error if the value is wrong? Do you want to remove a few obviously-wrong things (like newline at the end)? Once you precisely define the experience, we can help with the specific cases.

Comment: Yea I'd restrict the users input since its just a phrase they have to write. I have already fixed the whitespace problem, I just have to watch out for tabs or newlines. I was wondering if there was another solution other than just replacing "\n"

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there's no casting happening in your code. You pass a `String` to the init of `URL`, which isn't casting. Cast is done by using the type casting operator, `as`.

Comment: How would the user enter a newline in a text field?

Comment: Sorry Text area*

Answer (score 0):

Use optional binding (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html):

```swift
var str = "somescheme://somedata"

if let url = URL(string: str) {
    // handle url
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

If you want to strip whitespaces and new line characters, use:

```swift
str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```